# C# and .Net Garbage collector performance

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am trying to make a game in C# and .NET, and I was planning to implement messages that update the game objects in the game world. These messages would be C# reference objects.

I want this approach because doing it this way would be easier to send them over a network if I want the game to be multiplayer.

**But if I have a lot of messages, won't it be quite stressful for the garbage collector? And won't that affect gameplay?** The message classes themselves are quite small with 4 or 5 members at most.

These messages will be generated a couple of times per second for each object in the game world.

Comment: The GC in .net is Generational. Assuming that the messages are short lived then they should be mostly collected in the Level 0 generation. If so the performance shouldn't be too bad :)

Comment: you can ask here for better answers http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The overhead of transmitting all those messages over a network will be the limiting factor; the overhead of the GC will probably be negligible by comparison.

Comment: You should ask yourself how long those message objects are supposed to live. If they are rarely leaving gen0, there shouldn't be a problem. I suggest reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx).

Comment: For short lived objects the .net GC is pretty fast. But sending several messages per object per second over the network sounds problematic unless you have very few objects.

Comment: You might need to provide more information about the spec for this game. It sounds like there is some time constraint that may be bothered by the GC, but it's unclear.

In any case, just because the messages are short lived doesn't mean the game objects are. If they are medium-lived (ie not gen0 and not eternal) you may run into higher generational GCs.

It's all a question of how important a GC wait is to you.

Comment: As with most performance questions: build it and measure.

Comment: What is 'a lot' of messages?  Completely depends!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The GC in later versions, but more precisely 4.5, runs asynchronously for generations level 0 and 1. This has highly reduced the impact of GC.

If your objects are short-lived they should not pass from generation level 0 most of the time. Level 0 is the fastest generation to clean up by the GC.

Bottom line, I would not consider prematurely optimizing my code for fear of GC performance.

*Premature optimization is the root of all evil by*
 *DonaldKnuth*

Personally, i'd recommend this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx) for a deeper understanding

Comment: that really helps. I was planning on making the game on .net 4.5 anyway

Answer (score 24):

In .NET the garbage collector has 3 generations, generation 0, generation 1 and generation 2. Every Time the GC fails to collect an object in a generation, that object will be promoted to the next generation.

You could potentially run into issues if your objects are larger than 85kb. These objects will be automatically stored in the large object heap. The large object heap will be automatically collected in the following situations:

- Allocations exceed the large object heaps threshold.
- System is in a low memory situation.
- `System.GC.Collect` is called on generation 2.

The problem is that when the large object heap is collected, the memory for the objects is deallocated but the LOH is not compacted. Because the LOH is fragmented, you could potentially get `SystemOutOfMemory` exceptions thrown if there isn't a space big enough for your object on the LOH.

Techniques such as object pooling are commonly used to improve performance of the LOH.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx

**UPDATE:** .Net 4.5.1 will allow you to do on-demand compaction of the LOH within your application using the GC.Collect API.

Comment: This is an amazing answer and I don't know why it hasn't gotten more up votes. Clarified a lot about how the GC works (most of which I didn't know). +1

Comment: The link you provided is 5 years old and refers .NET 1.0 and 2.0; Do you know if the same is true for framework 4.0+ ? Thank you

Comment: Just found this link about LOH changes in .NET 4.5; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx